# Swift/ios/Google Maps - "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when adding UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a Navigation View Controller with a GMSMapView.

In my storyboard, I have dragged a UISlider over my MapView, but when I run, I don't even see it.  I've tried to set it up as both and IBOutlet and an IBAction, but feel like I'm missing something.  There's no slider visible when I run it.

Here is my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

and here is my code

```
class CircleSizeViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

let maxRadius : Double = 16093.4



var userLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

var centerMarker = GMSMarker()
var radiusMarker = GMSMarker()
var userMarker = GMSMarker()
var mRange = GMSMarker()
var isDragging = false
var isSizing = false
var isAtRange = false
var currentWidth : Double = 0.0
var currentHeading : Double = 0.0


var circ : GMSCircle = GMSCircle()



override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude, zoom: 15)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    centerMarker = GMSMarker(position: userLocation)
    radiusMarker = GMSMarker(position: GMSGeometryOffset(centerMarker.position, 300, 90))
    userMarker = GMSMarker(position: userLocation)
    mRange = GMSMarker(position: GMSGeometryOffset(centerMarker.position, maxRadius, GMSGeometryHeading(centerMarker.position, radiusMarker.position)))

    mRange.opacity = 0.0

    centerMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "sizemark")
    radiusMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "sizemark")
    mRange.icon = UIImage(named: "sizemark")
    centerMarker.isDraggable = true
    radiusMarker.isDraggable = true

    radiusMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
    centerMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)


    mRange.map = mapView
    centerMarker.map = mapView
    radiusMarker.map = mapView
    userMarker.map = mapView

    let circleCenter = centerMarker.position
    currentWidth = GMSGeometryDistance(centerMarker.position, radiusMarker.position)
    circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: currentWidth)
    circ.map = mapView

    mapView.insertSubview(slider, at: 1)
    mapView.delegate = self


}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
-T

Comment: Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: @rmaddy line 74  mapView.insertSubview(slider, at: 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. You're creating a map view in your storyboard and then you create a new one in your code. The slider therefore isn't a sub view of the map view. See: `mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)`
2. You then set the new map view to the view controller's view which removes the original map view from memory, and the slider is weak so that dies too.
3. Note for the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) (`UIViewController.loadView()`):

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the
>   view controller, you must not override this method.

**Potential solutions**

1. Don't use the storyboard at all. You can continue to use `loadView()` and everything should work fine. Just create your slider in code too.
2. Use the storyboard and add the slider. Then override `viewDidLoad()` and create the map view programmatically and insert it in your view controller's view (`self.view.insert(mapView, at: 0)`)